# webbrowser control SetAttribute does not respond programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, setattribute

i have application and i need to add text programmatically to some fields it works in most pages but in www.google.com when i try to but value to search, it did not work until i clicked on the text area then the value appear

is there any way to get around this

my code:

```
HtmlElementCollection el = webBrowser1.Document.All;
             foreach (HtmlElement H in el)
            {

                if (H.GetAttribute("type").Equals("text") )
                    H.SetAttribute("value", sendtext);

            }
```

i tried to click on it programmatically

```
object obj = H.DomElement;
System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi = obj.GetType().GetMethod("click");
mi.Invoke(obj, new object[0]);
```

also it does not work

Comment: are you using web browser control in a windows forms application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project + Add Reference, Browse tab and select c:\windows\system32\mshtml.tlb (.dll on earlier Windows versions).  This gives you access to the native COM interface that the DomElement property returns.  So you can write your code cleanly like this:

```
var obj = (mshtml.IHtmlElement)H.DomElement;
obj.click();
```

Or you can do it a bit less cleanly with the HtmlElement.InvokeMember() method:

```
H.InvokeMember("click");
```

A sample form that runs a google query using this technique:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("http://google.com");
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
    }

    void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
        if (webBrowser1.Url.Host.EndsWith("google.com")) {
            HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
            HtmlElement ask = doc.All["q"];
            HtmlElement lucky = doc.All["btnI"];
            ask.InnerText = "stackoverflow";
            lucky.InvokeMember("click");
        }
    }
}
```